# OS help (Can't find loader.o)

Tags: c++, gcc, operating-system

*Sorry for the long question* :/

---

I am following [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/zv07M4Gy/) tutorial on making a c++ OS. I followed the instructions through and fixed a few problems, but there is one thing that won't work.
*
I was at the step where you type in

```
gcc loader.o kernel.o -T linker.ld -o kern -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -lgcc
```

In the shell, and I get this:

> gcc: error: loader.o: No such file or directory

So i first thought that I missed a step(I didn't). Then I knew that I either need to download something, or my computer is missing something. If you know what i need to do, can you please tell me?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me like that page is missing the step that creates `loader.o`.

Comment: That tutorial is seriously flawed and lacking. I suggest you check out [OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) instead.

Comment: Yes, [Bare Bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) is the standard tutorial for writing a minimal kernel in C/C++.